# How to disable Zuul modifying request URL when forwarding to a service?

Tags: spring, routes, netflix-zuul

This is my Zuul configuration (.yml file)

```
server:
  port: 8080
zuul:
  sensitiveHeaders:
  ignored-services: "*"
  routes:
    ui-service:
      path: /online-book-store/**
      serviceId: ui-service-v1
      stripPrefix: true
    auth-service:
      path: /auth/**
      serviceId: auth-service
    book-service:
      path: /book-service/**
      serviceId: book-service
    book-service-genres:
      path: /api/genres/**
      serviceId: book-service
  host:
    socket-timeout-millis: 10000
    connect-timeout-millis: 10000


eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:2580/eureka/
```

The problem i'm confronting is that when i send a request:

```
<zuul_gateway>/api/genres/listAll
```

that request gets forwarded to 
    `<book-service>/listall` and i would prefer it to be `<book-service>/api/genres/listAll`

So all of the "matched" path gets removed. How can i disable this "feature"
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set *stripPrefix: false* to the book-service-genres. By default, matching prefixes are removed.

Comment: I don't think this works in this case since i don't have any prefixes defined actually, only services paths. And as documentation says:

zuul.stripPrefix only applies to the prefix set in zuul.prefix. It does not have any effect on prefixes defined within a given route’s path.